# How to await a forEach method

Tags: javascript

How do I await the forEach function so that I can console.log(posters)?

```
  let posters = [];

  reviews.forEach(async (review) => {
    // Get posters for reviews
    await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${review.filmId}?api_key=${tmdb_api}&language=en-US`)
      .then((data) => {
        posters.push(data.data.poster_path)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  })
  
  console.log(posters)
```

Important: I *cannot* put the console.log inside the .then() because I need the filled posters array *outside* of the forEach function.

Comment: Use `Promise.all()`

Comment: Also, see here https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated

Comment: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)